# Image width:auto and max-height after changing parent block height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please see example in chrome. I try to implement row height animation with image that shouldn't  exceed parent block.

Why does image width change only after changing any property [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JW3xX/2/)?

Try to click the first button, image height will updated, but width no. Then click the second button, opacity will changed, and image width will be setted properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image resizing</title>
    <style>
        .header-row {
            width:900px;
            height:90px;
            margin:0 auto;
            background:#0f3a51;
            -webkit-transition: all .9s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .9s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .9s ease;
            -o-transition: all .9s ease;
            transition: all .9s ease;
        }
        .header-row img {
            display: inline;
            max-height: 100%;
            background:#ff9900;
        }
        .header-row-reduced {
            height:50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="hr" class="header-row">
    <img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Volkswagen_Logo.png/600px-Volkswagen_Logo.png" alt="">
</div>
<button id="btn" onclick="check();">Update row height</button>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeProp();">Toggle opacity</button>
<script>
    var el = document.getElementById('hr'),
        img = document.getElementById('img');

    function check(){
        var classes = el.className.split(' '),
            hasClass = classes.indexOf('header-row-reduced');
        if(~hasClass) {
            classes.splice(hasClass,1);
        } else {
            classes.push('header-row-reduced');
        }
        el.className = classes.join(' ');
    }

    function changeProp() {
        img.style.opacity = '0.5';
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a good question. I don't know why this is not working like expected.

But you could fix it by applying the rule with the height to the element as well:

```
.header-row-reduced, .header-row-reduced img {
        height:50px;
}
```

This works, but I'm sure it is not exactly what you want to have!

Setting max-height in pixels should fix the issue as well.

Comment: Yes, this isn't what i want. And i have tried that as well. other thing to set img display:block. It seems inline and inline-block elements (img has display:inline as default value) can't work with max-height properly in such case.